# Функционал для отслеживания и реакции на происходящее в играх

Tags: java

Недавно пришла идея сделать для практики изучения языка программу, которая бы отслеживала определенные события в игре. Например: вела бы свой счетчик смертей или после окончания сессии внутри игры приложение предлагало заполнить нужную информацию в нем.
Однако совсем нет представления о инструментах позволяющих отслеживать что-то происходящее в запущенном софте. Поверхностный поиск ни к чему не привел, а точно и кратко сформулировать мысль для поисковика, что-бы он понял, не получается.

В какую сторону стоило бы начать копать и вообще реально ли это средствами java?

Comment: Целиком и полностью зависит от конкретной игры. Сколько-то реально для онлайн-игр, да и то, как повезет.

Comment: Десктопные игры. Ну, например Dota2

Comment: https://github.com/jeffreygroneberg/dota2stats - вот такое?

Comment: Хм, я так понимаю здесь все завязано на обращению к серверам Valve которые уже дадут информацию, если она есть? Мне желательно чтобы это было независимо от внешних источников, в основном потому что хотелось наблюдать за событиями которые судя по всему не отслеживаются ими. Допустим я вроде не нашел возможности анализировать первые смерти в матчах

Comment: Думаю, у вас это не выйдет. Потребуется как-то мониторить состояние памяти/временных файлов (что вообще далеко не задача для начинающего) на неизвестно какие изменения. Еще вариант - копать в сторону читов. Смотреть, какие события они могут отслеживать, и делать какой-то свой чит, работающий со статистикой

Comment: А нельзя хотя бы отследить конец матча на пк?